# Translate animation with image view not getting position properly

Tags: android, imageview, position, translate-animation

I have few issues in my code:

1.i'm using getX(), getY() to get the position of imageview in relative layout. Is it correct method to get positions?

2.Translate Animate doesn't stop with exact location.(i.e) it crosses image view(destination)

3.If animation ends to a particular position i want to set background image to this position
how can i achieve that that?

1. Is it logic wrong in continuous  animation? i used in animation end method..
   please provide your suggestions.
   i'm just a beginner.this is a small game i'm developing.

Here is my xml and java Code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:gravity="center_vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/player4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/player6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/player5"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/player5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="89dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/player4"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/player3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/player5"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/player2"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/player2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"        
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/player1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/player2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"       
     android:visibility="invisible"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/player7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/player1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/player6"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dealer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/player4"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My.java file

```
           //getting the imageviews from layout
    player1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.player1);
    player2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.player2);
    player3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.player3);
    player4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.player4);
    player5=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.player5);
    player6=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.player6);
    player7=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.player7);
    dealer=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.dealer);



     private void Logic() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


   if(players ==1)animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,addX.get(0),0,addY.get(0));
   if(players ==2)animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,addX.get(1),0, addY.get(1));
   if(players ==3)animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,addX.get(2),0, addY.get(2));
   if(players ==4)animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,addX.get(3),0, addY.get(3));
   if(players ==5)animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,addX.get(4),0, addY.get(4));
   if(players ==6)animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,addX.get(5),0, addY.get(5));
   if(players ==7)animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,addX.get(6),0, addY.get(6)); 
   }

  //Method for Start Animation

    private void doAnimation() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setFillAfter( true );
animation.setAnimationListener(this);
dealer.startAnimation(animation);
    }
//IN Animation END
   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

   dealer.clearAnimation();
   dealer.setImageResource(R.drawable.singlecard);
   players=players+1;
   dealer.clearAnimation();
    if(players<=count){
Logic();
    doAnimation();

    }
    }
```